# Issue with WSO2 ESB using JMS transport with IBM WMQ8

Tags: wso2-esb

I am trying to create a proxy service flow where I want to make a request to backend via JMS with WMQ 8.

The response from backend reaches the correct `reply_to_queue` but proxy service is not picking it.

In the logs I can see the errors:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueSession
```

The error goes away if make the service to one-way  by setting this property `<property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>`

Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

Below is error which I see in the logs:

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.AsyncCallback} -com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueSession {org.apache.synapse.    core.axis2.AsyncCallback}
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueSession
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.createConsumer(JMSUtils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.waitForResponseAndProcess(JMSSender.java:306)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendOverJMS(JMSSender.java:283)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:169)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Regards,
Gaurav